# Mean Calculation of a matrix within a Monte Carlo simulation in R

Tags: r, matrix, mean, montecarlo

In the following code, I am creating a Monte Carlo simulation of a projectile falling. I am fairly confident the simulation part of the code is right, but I am having trouble calculating the mean of the variable `g_estimate` (gravity) in the simulation. I calculate the `g_estimate` every iteration, but when I take the `mean`, it returns the same value as the `g_estimate`. I think this is because it calculates the `mean` for each iteration, when I want the overall `mean`. I want to create a matrix or vector to hold all of the `g_estimate` values, but I have not been successful so far. Here is the code:

```
#Monte Carlo simulation of distance formula equation
set.seed(1)
N <- 100000
g = 9.8
h0 = 56.67
v0 = 0
n = 25 #Number of devisions for time variable
tt = seq(0, 3.4, len = n) #Split time tt into 25 values between 0 and 3.4
y = h0 + v0 * tt - 0.5 * g * tt ^ 2 + rnorm(n, sd = 1) #Traces the path of the projectile
X = cbind(1, tt, tt ^ 2) #Define the matrix of variables
A = solve(crossprod(X)) %*% t(X) # A = (X^T X)^-1 X^T

replicate(N, {
    y = h0 + v0 * tt - 0.5 * g * tt ^ 2 + rnorm(n, sd = 1) #Traces the path of the projectile
    Exercise_Beta <- A %*% y #Returns a matrix of beta values
    g_estimate <- c(-2 * Exercise_Beta[3]) #Calculates g constant each iteration
    return(mean(g_estimate))
})
```

Any and all help is appreciated! Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `replicate...` to be within the `g_estimate` variable, and this code works:

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 100000
g = 9.8
h0 = 56.67
v0 = 0
n = 25 #Number of devisions for time variable
tt = seq(0, 3.4, len = n) #Split time tt into 25 values between 0 and 3.4
y = h0 + v0 * tt - 0.5 * g * tt ^ 2 + rnorm(n, sd = 1) #Traces the path of the projectile
X = cbind(1, tt, tt ^ 2) #Define the matrix of variables
A = solve(crossprod(X)) %*% t(X) # A = (X^T X)^-1 X^T
g_estimate <- matrix(replicate(N, {
    y = h0 + v0 * tt - 0.5 * g * tt ^ 2 + rnorm(n, sd = 1) #Traces the path of the projectile
    Exercise_Beta <- A %*% y #Returns a matrix of beta values
    return(-2 * Exercise_Beta[3])
    }))

mean(g_estimate)
```